# How to understand Poincaré's interpretation of Newton's anagram "aaaaabbbeeeeii"

Tags: newton, leibniz

In [Science and Method](https://archive.org/details/sciencemethod00poinuoft/page/36/mode/2up), page 37, Poincaré (as translated by Francis Maitland) states,

> The story goes that Newton once communicated to Leibnitz an anagram somewhat like the following: *aaaaabbbeeeeii*, etc.  Naturally, Leibnitz did not understand it at all, but we who have the key know that the anagram, translated into modern phraseology, means, "I know how to integrate all differential equations," and we are tempted to make the comment that Newton was either exceedingly fortunate or that he had very singular illusions.

Unfortunately, I fall in with Leibnitz in lacking the key to understanding this anagram, or even seeing how this is actually an anagram. An explanation of the relationship between Newton's cryptic message and the assertion that he knew how to integrate all differential equations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Poincare badly garbled both the anagram and what it meant, see [MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/140332/51484). Newton stated that he could extract coefficients of the power series for solutions to a DE assuming they are so representable.

Comment: Thanks!  Wow, that was really bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See more detail about this anagram (there were actually two of them) here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140327/arnold-on-newtons-anagram

Whatever the literal translation of the anagrams is, Newton indeed discovered
a method of solving "all equations" algebraic, differential, functional,
whatever. The method consisted in plugging a power series with undetermined coefficients and determining the coefficients one by one.

This was indeed a great idea, and it kept mathematicians busy ever since.